# "Создание кнопки ВВЕРХ" - почему так получается?

Tags: java, android

Изучаю Android JAVA по книге First Head.
В одной из глав написано, что для создания кнопки "ВВЕРХ"  нужно сделать два шага:

1. в манифесте указать для нашей активити - её родительскую активити (т.е. куда нужно вернуться)   android: parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
2. написать код:`ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`  Но возникает такая проблема:строка `actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` выдаёт ошибку : >"Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference"  Но дело в том, что если я выполняю только первый шаг и не выполняю второй, то кнопка "ВВЕРХ" появляется и нормально работает.
   Не пойму зачем нужен второй шаг если без него всё работает, а он, к тому же, вызывает ошибку?
   Подскажите, в чём тут дело?

Comment: От чего наследуется ваша Activity? возможно вам стоит использовать  getSupportActionbar()

Comment: Наследуется от AppCompatActivity. Попробовал getSupportActionbar() - всё работает!

Comment: вот собственно и ответ.
А тут есть более развернутый https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28144657/android-error-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-void-android-app-actionbar-on